# How do i get all h1 headings in google doc with google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

Basically, I want to get all the h1 heading in the active doc and change it into h2 also planning to do some font styling, etc.

```
function abc() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

 // instead of appending the paragraph in line 8 i want to get all the h1 heading that are avialble in the active document

 var par1 = body.appendParagraph("changing h1 to h2 heading");
 par1.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer to this sample code:

```
function findHeader() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  // Define the search parameters.
  var searchType = DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH;
  var searchHeading = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1;
  var searchResult = null;
  
  var style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

  // Search until the paragraph is found.
  while (searchResult = body.findElement(searchType, searchResult)) {
    var par = searchResult.getElement().asParagraph();
    if (par.getHeading() == searchHeading) {
      // Found one, update
      par.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);
      par.setAttributes(style);
    }
  }
}
```

### What it does?

1. Search for paragraphs in the document using [Body.findElement(elementType, from)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findelementelementtype,-from)
2. Check the heading of the current paragraph using [Paragraph.getHeading()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#getheading)
3. If the heading is `DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1`, set the heading to `DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2` and change its paragraph attributes using [Paragraph.setHeading(heading)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#setheadingheading) and [Paragraph.setAttributes(attributes)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#setattributesattributes)

### Output:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, i hardly meet such helpful people